# Solution to a ODE system using a power series

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm certain the pattern the system creates is

$$
A^kX(0) = \begin{pmatrix}2^k\\1\\2^k\end{pmatrix}\hspace{3pc}
$$

Where A is a matrix created by the system and X(0) is a solution vector at t=0

Im going to omit other info since it is not needed.

The rest of the answer I'm not to sure about.
Am I correct that the given pattern will then mean:
$$
X(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{2^k}{k!}t^k
$$

That is

$$
X(t) = e^t\begin{pmatrix}2^k\\1\\2^k\end{pmatrix}\hspace{3pc}
$$

?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. What is $k$ doing in the answer to a system of differential equations which don't involve $k$? (I'm assuming you're talking about a system of the form $dX/dt=AX$.)

Comment: Note that in the middle $1=1^k$. The completed series $X(t)$ does not depend on $k$. What can you say about the products $2^k·t^k$?

Comment: Sorry, was an error, $$
X(t) = e^t\begin{pmatrix}2^t\\1\\2^t\end{pmatrix}\hspace{3pc}
$$

Comment: But I'm not sure about the answer.

Comment: perhaps $$
X(t) = e^t\begin{pmatrix}e^2\\1\\e^2\end{pmatrix}\hspace{3pc}
$$
??

Comment: If you're unsure whether it's a solution or not, why don't you just plug the solution into the ODE to see if it's satisfied? (Most likely not, though. You should be looking for something involving $e^{2t}$ and $e^{1t}$.)

Comment: Its okay, I solved the problem using the eigenvalue/vector method. I need more practice with series otherwise solving the problem twice in a test or exam could cost me. Thanks for all the help